# How to get values using JavaScript from Html.BeginForm() ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to get display the values the user has typed after the "Add" button is pressed. But I don't know why my code displays undefined instead of the values.

I am passing multiple instances of my model objects to the controller as a list.

This is my View:

```html
@model List<MVCModel.Models.Student>

 <b>Result</b>    @ViewBag.s <br />
  
@using (Html.BeginForm("Form", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table>
    <tbody id="GenaratorList">
        <tr>
          @{
            int counter = 0;
            <td>Enter Name: </td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[counter].Name)</td>
            <td>Enter Age: </td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[counter].Age)</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addGenarator()" /></td>
        </tr>
        counter++;
        }
     <tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>
}

<script>
    count = 0;
    function addGenarator() {
        var Name = $('#Name').val();
        var Age = $('#Age').val();
        var Student = "studentModels[" + count + "]";
        $('#GenaratorList').append('<tr><td><input id="' + Student + '.Name" Name="' + Student + '.Name" type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="' + Name + '"></td><td><input id="' + Student + '.Age" Age="' + Student + '.Age" type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="' + Age + '"></td></tr>');
        $('#Name,#Age').val('');
        count++;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You aren't iterating your list for one.  When razor renders the `TextBoxFor` on an item in a collection, it's going to have a more complex id than `Name`.  You should look at the generated html on the page to figure out what the id is.

Answer (score 0):

You have not assigned id to the textboxfor kindly assign the id

```html
@model List<MVCModel.Models.Student>

 <b>Result</b>    @ViewBag.s <br />
  
@using (Html.BeginForm("Form", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table>
    <tbody id="GenaratorList">
        <tr>
          @{
            int counter = 0;
            <td>Enter Name: </td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[counter].Name, new {id = "Name"})</td>
            <td>Enter Age: </td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[counter].Age, new {id = "Age"})</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addGenarator()" /></td>
        </tr>
        counter++;
        }
     <tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>
}

<script>
    count = 0;
    function addGenarator() {
        var Name = $('#Name').val();
        var Age = $('#Age').val();
        var Student = "studentModels[" + count + "]";
        $('#GenaratorList').append('<tr><td><input id="' + Student + '.Name" Name="' + Student + '.Name" type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="' + Name + '"></td><td><input id="' + Student + '.Age" Age="' + Student + '.Age" type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="' + Age + '"></td></tr>');
        $('#Name,#Age').val('');
        count++;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Form (HttpPost) API was expected to receive a request body with an array named s. You will pass the array as (name) studentModels based on your JS code.
And you miss out on the name attribute for each Age input.

make sure the array name in View must be matched with the Controller parameter name.
use this script

```
    <script>
    count = 0;
    function addGenarator() {
        var Name = $('#Name').val();
        var Age = $('#Age').val();
        var Student = "s[" + count + "]";

        var html = `
        <tr>
            <td><input id="${Student}.Name" name="${Student}.Name" type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="${Name}" /></td>
            <td><input id="${Student}.Age" name="${Student}.Age" type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="${Age}" /></td>
        </tr>
    `;
        $('#GenaratorList').append(html);
        $('#Name,#Age').val('');
        count++;
    }
</script>
```